# Execution of code in the background when the event is triggered

Tags: c#, .net, background, event-handling, uwp

I'm currently doing all the work in the event itself, but this doesn't seem to be the preferred way since the code doesn't execute on phones after a few minutes of inactivity. The event declaration goes as follows:

```
public PlaybackModel()
{
    ...
    queue.CurrentItemChanged += async (o, ea) =>
    {
        var res = ScrobbleHelper.TrySend(ea.OldItem);
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            var bg = App.Ref.IsBackground;
            currentItem = o.CurrentItem;
        });
    };
    ...
}
```

There seem to be 5 possible outcomes for this event:

1. The scrobble works properly when the app is in the foreground;
2. The scrobble works properly when the app is working in the background with the screen turned on (user is doing something else);
3. The scrobble is working properly when the screen was turned off recently (when the request was sent shortly after turning off the screen)
4. The scrobble can't be sent so it gets cached instead when screen is turned off for over a minute (seems like the internet connection is getting cut off, so the scrobble gets cached locally);
5. The code isn't executed at all if the screen was turned off for long period of time.

With this in mind I was considering using a In-Process Background Task with the `ApplicationTrigger` to call the scrobbler but I'm not sure how I could go about this.

On one hand this is the only thing that comes to mind that can execute code without the app running in the foreground, but on second hand, if the code itself isn't called by the event handler, I'm not sure if the task will get triggered.

Is there any other API or feature of UWP that can be helpful in thissituation? If not, how can I implement the background task to achieve maximum effectiveness?

Thank you!

Comment: What is it that is triggering the event in the first place? Wondering if any of the background triggers would be applicable to your scenario. This way your app can suspend normally and the system would wake up your code whenever the trigger fires.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background

Comment: This event is triggered by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacklist) Microsoft API. I'm using the MediaPlayer class to play the music. How do I call these background triggers, from where and how do I tie everything together?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows devices there are some constraints about running background events in foreground applications, i.e. they are frozen when screen is off for a certain period of time. It is to reduce battery consumption, the whole process gets suspended in memory and no events are fired.

There do is a way to run a background task on a dedicated process which will function properly even if the device is unused for some time. You'd need to create a dedicated class implementing `IBackgroundTask`, then just pin it to appropriate trigger and register it. (If the app has to write things into application state, you'd also need some IPC interface to consider since background tasks run as a different process.)

Comment: So then the In-Process task is not a good solution for this? How would I go about implementing and, more importantly, triggering the Out-of-Process Background Task if the events are not being called in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app is playing back media and you want to prevent it from being suspended when the app goes to the background or the screen gets locked. The best way to do this is to use the new in-process background media playback capability that has been released last year with the Anniversary Update (1607). Here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio

One caveat to note is that the OS might put the network adaptor to sleep when not in use. From the symptom you describe this might be what you are hitting here. Try adding this code to your app to ensure the network connectivity remains active even when the screen gets locked:

```
Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer mp;
public void CreatePlayer()
{
  Windows.Media.Core.MediaBinder mb = new Windows.Media.Core.MediaBinder();
  mb.Binding += Mb_Binding;           
  var ms = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromMediaBinder(mb);
  mp = new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer();
  mp.CommandManager.IsEnabled = false;
  mp.Source = ms;
}

private void Mb_Binding(Windows.Media.Core.MediaBinder sender, Windows.Media.Core.MediaBindingEventArgs args)
{
  var d = args.GetDeferral();
}
```

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: I *am* using it.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood the problem description. Is your problem that the app gets suspended or that your network connectivity gets disconnected?

Comment: Both, actually. While the `Background Media Playback` capability enables background media playback, it still doesn't give me full control over it. The media does play in the background, but any events that should respond to events raised by the `MediaPlayer` or `MediaPlaybackList` don't work that well. Especially after longer periods of inactivity. The article you linked does mention this and says that I need to use a background task with either `MaintananceTrigger` or `TimerTrigger`, but that woudln't work in my scenario, as it *needs* to be called whenever the song finishes playing not 15min

Comment: So basically, what you've send me I have already established and in this question I'm looking for more details and info on how to implement the task so that it behaves as similarly to what I have in the original question (the event) as possible. I need this task to be called every time the song is changed -- either by clicking a button or simply because it finished playing. That's why events seem to be the best solution, unfortunately they don't work in the background.

I'm not sure what type of background task I should use and I don't know what is the best trigger for this scenario.

Comment: By declaring the capability, your app will not get suspended as long as it is playing media, and events will keep firing as normal. However, if the functionality depends on network connectivity you are likely hitting a power saving feature of the OS where the network adaptor is put to sleep when not in use. I'll edit the answer to add a workaround that will ensure the connectivity remains active.

Comment: That's not quite right. The `TryScrobble()` method is supposed to scrobble the finished track to the Last.FM API or, if that fails, it should cache the scrobble locally for later. That is indeed what happens when I turn off Wi-Fi and Mobile Data manually. However, when the device's screen is turned off, it doesn't do either of these things. The event just isn't being called even though the media is playing in the background.

Comment: Have you tried adding the workaround code from my answer to your app, to prevent the network from going to sleep? If that doesn't help I'd suggest you update your question with a complete code sample that demonstrates the problem.